# SIMULINK - Strange Sine wave plot

Tags: matlab, simulink

So I'm new to Simulink (I've been working on it for less than 1 hour). I've put a "Sine Wave" block with an amplitude of 3 and a frequency of 2*pi and connected it to a "Scope". The problem is that the plot has some kind of edges:

[image]

Would you mind telling me, please, how to fix this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because by default Simulink chooses a time step of the simulation end time divided by 50, unless the dynamics of the model requires smaller time steps (for a variable step solver).

I assume you haven't changed any of the solver settings, in which case you probably have `ode45` as a solver with the default settings. Change the `MaxStepSize` to be something small, say 0.1s or even smaller. The simulation will take a bit longer but you'll get more data points and therefore a smoother curve.

Have a read of [Choose a Solver](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/types-of-solvers.html) in the Simulink documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the path to solver settings:
Your Simulink model -> Modeling -> Model Settings -> Model Settings -> Solver -> Solver: ode45, Max step size: 0.1.